# How to cover fixed size container with child image keeping full width/height ratio?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, less

So I have a 300x300 square container and an `<img src="" />` image inside.

What I want is the image to cover the whole container, but keep its width/height ratio.

- If the width of the image is smaller than its height (portrait), it should have 100% width and a part of the height to be cropped.
- If the height is smaller than the width (landscape), it should have 100% height and the extra width to be cropped.

I can easily fit the images in the container if they're all landscape or all portrait by setting the width or height to `100%` and respectively the height or width to `auto`:

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/949587/pexels-photo-949587.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" />
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://yada.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/55846576-textured-floral-dark-blue-background-abstract-vertical-background-.jpg" />
</div>
```

but is there any universal **HTML/CSS ONLY** approach to make it automatically cover the container regardless the orientation?

**Note 1**: The inner image **should not be distorted in any way**. It should only fit the container by the rules described above.

**Note 2**: I'm curious about an approach that **doesn't imply** `background-image: url('')`

Comment: you can try "object-fit:cover" on your img tag along with height and width as 100%. This will help cover the entire container without any distortion and should work for all scenarios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried what *Sitaram* suggested in the comments section of the question and it seems to be the optimal solution.

Besides the fact that the images would cover the entire square, they would cover the container regardless the width or height.

Snippet:

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: both;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/949587/pexels-photo-949587.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" />
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://yada.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/55846576-textured-floral-dark-blue-background-abstract-vertical-background-.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
 width: fit-content;
  min-height:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/949587/pexels-photo-949587.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" />
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://yada.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/55846576-textured-floral-dark-blue-background-abstract-vertical-background-.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, adding a `min-height` will make the first image in the snippet distort. It goes to 100% container width and to a fixed 300px height although the ratio makes it less than 300px. Please read **Note 1** at the bottom of the question.